# Rendering php file in twitter bootstrap

Tags: php, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I'll try to keep it simple. I downloaded [bootstrap template](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/modern-business/). It has contact.php file along with a bunch of html files. I use node.js app that I deploy on heroku. The problem happens when I go to contact item: it suggests me to save that php file instead of opening it in a browser. My web.js file is currently following:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var htmlFile = './modern-business/index.html'

// Log requests
app.use(express.logger());

//Serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'modern-business')));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  //response.send('Hello, there.');
    var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlFile).toString();
    response.send(html);   
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

How can I fix this? Basically I want the same functionality as in original template.

P.S. I will accept the answer that solves the problem.

Comment: Why is php file in template ? Is it for php framework ?

Comment: Php file has contact form along with google map. That's my understanding why they have php file. Here is the [page](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/modern-business/contact.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have deployed your NodeJS app inside a NodeJS container in Heroku. This means there is no PHP interpreter which is why the server sends the file to the browser to download since it does not know how to handle the PHP file. So you have 2 choices:

1. Rewrite your contact form and make it such that the form submits to the NodeJS app and from the NodeJS app handle the submission (email, database, etc)
2. Have your contact form hosted on another PHP container on heroku or any other site and link to that

Comment: How would I host PHP in another container? Just make another app for php and redirects contact form to that page?

Comment: Thats right. You can check on google if you need more info on how to deploy PHP apps to heroku

Comment: But if rewrite php file in node.js, will it render without modification in web.js file?

Comment: You will require modifications to your web.js file for sure. What you would do is have your HTML file POST to a route in your web.js file and from there you will have to write the appropriate code to either email the submission or store it in a database or some other way based on your requirements.

Comment: How html POSTs to a route? html is client-side, isn't it?

Comment: I guess you are not very familar with NodeJS :D No worries, here is a link to walk you thru the steps involved and as a bonus it also is heroku compatible :) http://dailyjs.com/2012/09/13/express-3-csrf-tutorial/